# Mapping domain to AWS instance won't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I want to map an AWS instance to a registered domain from my national domain provider.

In my domain's panel, I am asked to provide:

- Primary DNS Hostname
- Primary DNS Netaddress
- Secondary DNS Hostname
- Secondary DNS Netaddress

Here's my **AWS instance:**

[image]

and my **Domain panel:**

[image]

In the Primary DNS Hostname and Primary DNS Netaddress fields, I have included my instance's Public DNS and Public IP respectively.

Did I provide correct data in my domain's panel? Additionally, where can I find my instance's Secondary DNS Hostname and DNS Netaddress?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are running your down DNS server, you are doing this wrong.

You should connect your registrar ('domain provider') to Amazon's Route 53. [Here are Amazon's steps to migrate to Route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html). There will be four nameservers to use in your hosted zone ('dns domain', roughly). If your registrar only takes two, that's okay.

I'd very strongly suggest not entering anything in the IP ('netaddress'), as AWS changes the IPs.

If you have any trouble, share the registrar you are using.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @tedder42. I have followed your steps and now  I have 4 name servers. I have included two of them in the domain panel, but the form wont submit with IP addresses left blank... Should I include there my elastic IP? Many thanks in advance

Comment: the IP addresses change. You could look them up and include them, but no guarantees that it won't break. You can ask your registrar or list it here in case anyone has experience with that specific registrar.